# I want to compare the data in two different dates found in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to compare the data in two different dates found in MySQL.

For example:

```
Date         Sale   ProductName
----------------------------------------
2017-01-01   1258   Product1
2017-01-01   345    Product2
2017-01-01   3452   Product3
2017-01-02   1135   Product1
2017-01-02   496    Product2
2017-01-02   3559   Product3
```

I want to bring incremental sales figures between two dates.

How can I do it.

Sample output:

```
Product Name   2017-01-01  2017-01-02   Increase
--------------------------------------------------------
Product2       345         496          +151  
Product3       3452        3559         +107
```

Comment: Show us the result that you would like

Comment: Sample output please..

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding service ___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (Dt date, Sale int, prod varchar(10));
insert into t values
('2017-01-01', 1258 ,'Product1'),
('2017-01-01', 345  ,'Product2'),
('2017-01-01', 3452 ,'Product3'),
('2017-01-02', 1135 ,'Product1'),
('2017-01-02', 496  ,'Product2'),
('2017-01-02', 3559 ,'Product3');

select prod,dt,sale,
         if(t.prod <> @p, @rt:=t.sale,(@rt:=@rt  - t.sale) * -1) Diff,
         @p:=t.prod p
from  (select @rt:=0 ,@p:=0) rt,t
order by  prod,dt,sale
```